# Is there a way to make a DIY EEG?

Tags: eeg, electrophysiology

I have MATLAB. I would like to try out a small EEG project because my field of interest is in neuroscience, however I'm still doing my undergrad.

Comment: Instead of DIY you could also buy commercial grade EEG. Though it is not perfect equipment, it may be good enough for you and relatively "cheap". The best possibility is Emotiv EPOC or Emotiv Insight. However, I heard there are some support issues (the lack of support). Have you also tried to ask your university to see if you can borrow one? EEG systems are rarely used throughout the year.

Comment: I go to a community college at the moment..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [OpenEEG](http://openeeg.sourceforge.net/doc/) project has some information for building your own EEG system. [Instructables has a "simple" EEG circuit](http://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-EEG-and-ECG-Circuit/) you can build. Note that this is going to be somewhat costly and time consuming because you are dealing with tiny voltages and high impedances.

[OpenBCI](http://openbci.com/) has some hardware for sale (still expensive but not as bad as research-grade equipment) and their [forum](http://openbci.com/index.php/forum/) can be helpful for the DIY EEG enthusiast.

You also might want to look into utilizing some existing publicly available EEG datasets instead of collecting the data yourself:

- [BCNI](http://bnci-horizon-2020.eu/database/data-sets)
- [UCI](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/EEG+Database)
- [NIAL](https://sites.google.com/site/neuroinformaticsimageanalysis/home/data-repositories)
- [UCSD](http://sccn.ucsd.edu/~arno/fam2data/publicly_available_EEG_data.html)
- [More links](http://www.brainsignals.de/)